# Repeating characters in VIM insert mode

Tags: vim

Is there a way of repeating a character while in Vim's insert mode?  For example, say I would like to insert 80 dashes, in something like emacs I would type:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>   <kbd>8</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd>

The only way I know how to do it in VIM is to exit normal mode for the repeat argument, then go back into insert mode to type the dash, then exit to insert the actual dashes, AND then go back into insert mode to carry on typing.  The sequence is a really long:

<kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>8</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd>

It would be nice not to switch in and out of modes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Slightly different version of Eelvex's solution:

```
function! Repeat()
    let times = input("Count: ")
    let char  = input("Char: ")
    exe ":normal a" . repeat(char, times)
endfunction

imap <C-u> <C-o>:call Repeat()<cr>
```

Answer (score 319):

If you are OK with leaving INSERT mode only once (at the end), this sequence works:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> `80i-` <kbd>Esc</kbd>

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> is used to issue normal commands without leaving INSERT mode,
- `80` the repetition,
- `i` to insert,
- `-` the character you want to insert,
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> to leave INSERT mode.

Another one without EVER leaving INSERT mode:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> `:norm 8ia` <kbd>Return</kbd>

Comment: Your answer and the OP's answer are the only ones that work for me.

Comment: "<C-o> is used to issue normal commands without leaving INSERT mode" wins my can't-believe-I-never-knew-about-this award!

Comment: `<C-o>` is shorthand for `Ctrl` + `o`.

Comment: There's also the `:normal` command which lets you issue them from the command prompt.  Occasionally quite useful.

Answer (score 204):

<kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>*n*</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>*c*</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> .

E.g. <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> will output `JJJJ`.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work on my vim unless you escape back to normal mode.

Comment: But this is the best answer in the "vim way".

Comment: I always find myself going back to insert mode when I press the i, so then I will only insert CHARACTER. How do I work this?

Comment: I like this answer but on MacVim, I get an annoying beep when pressing the first Esc, as though warning me I did something invalid. Oh well I can get used to it.

Comment: This is the exact sequence of commands the OP wanted to *avoid*.

Comment: This may not be the answer to the question that was asked, but its the vim way to do it and it's the answer to the question I was looking for.

Comment: @SeveroRaz did you managed how to solve that? I'm also into that. When I press `i` I enter the insert mode.

Comment: @SolidSnake yeah, it doesn't matter that you go to insert mode again. When you press the `i` you go into insert mode, then you type in the character you want and press `Esc` again; then the string appears.

Comment: For me only one ESC at the end is enough. I'm inserting 80 `-` to form a split line. So I do: `<ESC>80i-<ESC>`

Comment: I works for me but I don't understand -- 'i' will change the environment back to insert mode, then '-' will insert "-" character, and why <ESC> will return to normal mode and repeat previous operations?

Comment: @Qiao `80i(...)<esc>` means do the insert action 80 times. What you type until the <esc> defines what that insert action is.

Answer (score 49):

Through single repeat:

1. Press: <kbd>i</kbd> to enter into Insert mode
2. Press: <kbd>-</kbd>
3. Press: <kbd>Esc</kbd>
4. Press: <kbd>8</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>

It will output: 81 `-`, like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

More details about single repeat: `:help .`

Comment: Thanks but this solution requires you to go out of insert mode.

Comment: This is trully `vim` language... This is why it is the best answer.

Comment: That's my winner. Also you can do `. + ENTER` repeatedly to add more reps

Comment: I like this, but you will end up with 81 characters in total.

Comment: For me this was a bit confusing. I use VIM in vscode, and had to press 80, then 'i', '-' and esc last to get it to repeat like you say in this answer. Then I got 80 and not 81 chars as well.

Comment: ok, I changed 80 on 81 :)

Answer (score 24):

```
<ESC> 
<the number of times you want to repeat>
i 
<the char you want to repeat> 
<ESC>

for example: <ESC>12ia<ESC> will insert 12 a's.
```

Comment: This is the exact sequence of commands the OP wanted to *avoid*.

Answer (score 13):

You can also do,
    **<kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>*n*i</kbd><kbd>hello there</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>**

where, 
n is the number of repeats.

e.g., 
    <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>5i</kbd><kbd>hello there</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>

Comment: This looks like an exact duplicate of [Martin Beckett's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5054183/627727)

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate. The other one didn't work for me. Here I realized I have to press `Esc` twice afterwards. Thanks @prashant

Answer (score 13):

I'm surprised no one has suggested this yet:

In Insert mode, use `<C-r>=repeat('-', 80)<CR>`

That is:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>
- At the resulting prompt, enter `repeat('-', 80)`
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Works for repeating any character any number of times.

This uses more keystrokes than @romainl's answer, but does not leave Insert mode at all.

Comment: Not only can't I believe that no one suggested this so late, but also that your solution has so less up-votes. I was looking / hoping that something exactly like this(with Ctrl-r) would exist, and I almost closed this tab but I am so lucky that I found this. Awesome dude thank you :)

Answer (score 8):

There are many other ways but AFAIK the one you describe is the shortest one. In *vim* you are mostly supposed to spend your time in command mode, so that would be just 3 keystrokes + the number of repeats (80i-).

However, if you find that you very often use this repeat thing, you can make yourself a function or macro to that end; maybe something like:

```
:function Repeat(char)
: let counter = input("How many times?: ")
: call feedkeys("i")
: call feedkeys(repeat(a:char,counter))
:endfunction
:imap <C-U> <ESC>h"ryl :call Repeat(@r)<CR>
```

Comment: It didn't work for me but thanks for the answer.  My knowledge of the vim programming language is not good enough to figure out why.

Answer (score 8):

You said it would be 'nice' to stay in 'Insert' mode, however in Command Mode the following method would avoid your 2nd <kbd>ESC</kbd> :-

While I know this post is old, it seems a shame to miss the obvious 'Cut/Copy and Paste' option...

<kbd>x</kbd> ...cut

<kbd>8</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> ...number of copies

<kbd>p</kbd> Paste

*Note : This is similar to the method suggested by Martin Beckett, however I get a delay when issuing that command, perhaps because it switches modes several times, this command executes instantly.*

Comment: I had to use `v` `y` to enter visual mode, then yank, then `80` `p` to paste it 80 times. Am I missing something, or did you forget a step?

Comment: Well spotted, I should have used 'x' to cut, then paste.  Thank you I have amended my answer.

Comment: nice since this is actually faster than the typical repeat method.

Comment: i have to say this is a much better solution than any others, because it covers any character you can imagine.

Answer (score 3):

Late answer but for what it's worth, if you wanna hand spam it, you can use the 
"repeat last command" command:  `.`

<kbd>i</kbd> "Phrase"  <kbd>Esc</kbd>  - `i to insert, enter phrase/character, esc to go normal mode`

<kbd>.</kbd> - `Spam till you are satisfied. Will repeatedly input the phrase you typed (it repeats your last command).`

I find this especially useful when I don't know exactly how many repeats I want to do, but know visually how long I want it to be. Basically blast the `.` till my eyes are content.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to writing function that will repeat text multiple times, you could use <kbd><C-x><C-l></kbd>: if you already have line that contains 80 dashes, writing a few dashes at the start of new line and then pressing <kbd><C-x><C-l></kbd> will complete lines which start with these few dashes which will be likely that line with 80 dashes. I used to write horizontal lines (78 dashes) in help files in a such way.

Answer (score 2):

For such an easy task [`abbreviation`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#abbreviations) should do the trick.  Add the following to your `.vimrc`

```
iab <expr> -- repeat('-', 80)
```

and from now, when you type `--` followed by a space (while you are in insert mode), the `--` will be automatically converted to `-` 80 times.

By using the function [`repeat`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#repeat%28%29) you are able to repeat the string as many time you want.

Note that you can test it before updating the `.vimrc` by entering in `command` mode then issuing the following `:iab <expr> -- repeat('-', 80)`

Answer (score 1):

I did this without exiting the INSERT mode using the below steps.

1. Enable INSERT mode.
2. Type one dash "-".
3. Ctrl + O
4. lowercase 'v' (to enter `-- (insert) VISUAL --` mode)
5. lowercase 'y' (to copy)
6. Ctrl + O
7. Type 80
8. Then, followed by lowercase 'p' (for paste).

`i` `-` `Ctrl+o` `v` `y` `Ctrl+o` `80` `p`

This will print all the dashes horizontally in a single line.